# Use exported class as type in a .d.ts

Tags: typescript

I have `./class1.ts` and `./class2.ts` which both look like this:

```
export class Class1{ ... }
```

and

```
export class Class2{ ... }
```

In `./run.ts` I have a function that takes a class input

```
function doSomething(klass: ClassType){
    let foo = new klass()
}
```

In `./typings.d.ts` I have:

```
type ClassType = Class1 | Class2
```

I get an error in `typings.d.ts` saying that `Class1` and `Class2` cannot be found.

Adding

```
/// <reference path="./class1.ts" />
```

Causes no errors but does not solve the problem.

Adding

```
import {Class1} from './class1.ts'
```

Fixes the problem in `./typings.d.ts` but it then causes all my typing to be unusable in the project.

How do I use exported classes as types in my project?

Comment: Could you provide a small example, perhaps in webpackbin : https://www.webpackbin.com/ ?

Comment: Just getting `ts-loader` errors on there

Comment: Indead, webpackbin seems broken, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Change typings.d.ts to typings.ts with content:

```
import { Class1 } from './class1'
import { Class2 } from './class2'

export type ClassType = Class1 | Class2
```

and run.ts to

```
import { ClassType } from './typings'

function doSomething(klass: ClassType) {
    let foo = new klass()
}
```

`import`/`export` and `/// <reference path="..." />` are two different loading concept you shouldn't mix those.

Comment: That throws loads of 'X' is declared but never used in `typings.ts`

Comment: Is there some other declaration in typings.ts?